# zend framework 2 flash messenger error

Tags: zend-framework2

I am facing this error in flashmessenger Version 2.1.0

```
Warning: Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer in /home/test/public_html/index.php on line 17 Fatal error: Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger::getMessages(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Zend\Stdlib\SplQueue" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/test/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin/FlashMessenger.php on line 288

In index.php : session is started in line 17.
```

In controller:

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Updated Successfully.'); 


$flashMessenger = $this->flashMessenger(); 
if($flashMessenger->hasMessages()) { 
     $return['messages'] = $flashMessenger->getMessages(); 
}
```

Please help am i did anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem i upgraded to version `2.2.2` and removed the `session_start()` in `index page` everything working fine.